# Can we detect if autoplay sound is blocked on Firefox 66 and greater?

Tags: javascript, web, firefox, video

Firefox just started blocking autoplaying of videos. I personally am a fan of this but there are times it is very clear the visitor wants it to autoplay.

For example, we built an online course platform that uses `<video autoplay>`. I want to detect if the default blocking is still active or whether they have selected "allow on this site":

[image]

Is there a simple API or call we can make to detect this and show a help screen that they can whitelist our domain if they do want this (99% of the time they do)?

Comment: Never played with it but `navigator` object has a `permissions` property you could look at

Comment: Thanks, tried `navigator` but permissions is just `{}`. Good idea!